IIS 10 Configuration .Net Core/Angular and .Net Framework ASPX.Net issue
I am setting up a new Windows 2019 server with IIS 10.
I am trying to configure two web applications within the server.
One is a .Net Core/Angular 16 application, the other is a .Net Framework ASP.Net application.
On a previous server, we had two sites, one at port 80/443 (ASP.Net) and one at 8080/8443 (.Net/Angular)
What I am trying to do is get rid of the port numbers, by moving one application into a folder, while having the other remain at the root.
Our preference is for the Angular application to be at the root:
https://myapp.somehost.com/ <-- Angular Application
https://myapp.somehost.com/aspx <-- ASP.Net application
The .NetCore/Angular app is working as expected, but with having the ASPX application in a folder, I can't get past the authentication using WS Federation.
When accessing the site as: https://myapp.somehost.com/aspx
In Chrome's  Network tab, I see the redirects to the WS Fed Auth server
Get: aspx
Get: prp.wsf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https...%252faspx&wct=...
Get: prp.ping
Post: aspx - 500 error
And in the browser I see:
ID3206: A SignInResponse message may only redirect within the current web application: '/aspx' is not allowed.
While I found some suggestions about adding a trailing slash to the URL, when I do that I get an immediate 500 internal server error, with no authentication redirection, and I can't find anything describing that error anywhere (Event Viewer, IIS logs, etc)
After 6 hours of searching this issue, I only have myself more confused.
Maybe having the .Net Core/Angular app as the top-level app is the problem? I'm not sure.
Hoping someone may have tried to do this before and can point me in the right direction.
Thanks

May i know have you created separate app pool for both application? Could you share the structure of the site and application? How are you adding the trailing slash in the url? what does your WS-Federation Configuration look like? have you set your new app path in that configuration? You could try to enable iis failed request tracing and detailed logging to more information about the issue. Enable detailed error message in iis: Open IIS Manager, select your website Double-click on the "Error Pages" Click "Edit Feature Settings" on the right-hand side. Choose "Detailed errors" and click "OK."

Yes, I have two app pools created, one 'v4.0' and one 'No Managed Code'
I created a site named 'ngx', for the .Net Core/Angular app using the 'No Managed Code' pool
I created an application inside 'ngx' named 'aspx' and have that using the 'v4.0' pool
I am waiting for our ping-fed admin to add the realm/return URL with the trailing slash in the name, in hopes that helps.
I did install additional packages for IIS for request tracking, but the piece I was missing was the 'Edit Feature Settings' you mentioned.
I will have to see if that helps. Thanks!

I have gotten farther.
From the looks of it, I am past the ws-fed authentication.
Now I am getting a 503 response when trying to access pages for the nested ASP.net site...

could you share the new error snapshot here.

You could create a new app pool for both  the site and application instead of using the default created one. and use the .net 4 for both the app pool

Please first create an empty IIS site (with just some static HTML pages for testing), and then add your ASP.NET web app as an application under it. That allows you to test out any issue hosting it as an application and make all related code changes. In the end, you can move the Angular/.NET Core web app in and troubleshoot issues related to that. Don't attack both the same time.

Apologies for not responding to my post, another higher priority issue impacting a production system at work has had me swamped and I haven't had an opportunity to get back to update.  I did manage to get this working, with a default IIS website at root, and each app in a folder. A redirect rule sends the user from root to Angular app as a starting point. Hopefully will han a chance  to post more details tomorrow

The solution I found to this issue was to organize the IIS site like this:

Site: myapp
Application 1: ng

(with a pool configured for 'No Managed
Code')


Application 2: aspx

(with a pool configured for .NET CLR v4.0)



Verified bindings for both http and https.
At site level, defined 'HTTP Redirect' to: https://myapp.somehost.com/ng
with redirect behavior: Only redirect to content in this directory (not subdirectories)
The redirect gets the users to the Angular application by default.
Now that both applications share the same hostname, without any port numbers involved, redirection between the two sites now looks like the same CORS domain, so working with IFrames is now possible.
Before I got side tracked on other priorities, I was able to configure an Angular component that I named AspxFrameComponent, which takes a URL of one of the ASPX pages as an input parameter, and displays that page in an iframe element.
Taking this approach, we now should be able to embed the ASPX pages seamlessly into our Angular application, until we can complete migrating the remaining pages from ASPX to Angular.
The advantage of iframe embedding is being able to use common navigation, implemented in Angular, rather than jumping between the two application in the same browser window (losing the Angular app state) or opening new pages in new tabs (again, losing angular state)
I am still not entirely sure why I can't define the top-level site as the angular site, and embed the ASPX app as an application within, but doing both as applications, with an 'empty' top-level site appears to work just fine.
